# Handle Keyboard events for iron-list in GWT?

Tags: javascript, html, gwt, polymer, polymer-1.0

I use [iron-list](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-list) from google Polymer.

```
<iron-list items="[[data]]" as="item">
  <template>
    <div tabindex$="[[tabIndex]]">
      Name: [[item.name]]
    </div>
  </template>
</iron-list>
```

I kwon you can use [Polymer.IronA11yKeysBehavior](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-a11y-keys-behavior) but even with the [example](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-a11y-keys-behavior?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=Polymer.IronA11yKeysBehavior) I have no idea how I add it in JavaScript to my iron-list.

Using [Vaadin Polymer GWT lib](https://github.com/vaadin/gwt-polymer-elements). In this lib you have

```
IronList list; 
list.setKeyBindings(???);  // don't know how to use this function
list.setKeyEventTarget(????);  // don't know how to use this function
```

When I check the current values of the key bindings I defined a print function to log a variable to the console:

public native void print(JavaScriptObject obj) /*-{
    console.log(obj);
  }-*/;

Then I print the current values with:

```
print(list.getKeyBindings());
```

The result is:

```
Object {up: "_didMoveUp", down: "_didMoveDown", enter: "_didEnter"}
```

It seem that there are some key bindings already defined, but I have no idea where I find the functions `_didMoveUp`, `_didMoveDown` and `_didEnter`.

When I do

```
print(list.getKeyEventTarget());
```

I get:

```
<iron-list class="fit x-scope iron-list-0" tabindex="1" style="overflow: auto;">
</iron-list>
```

**How can I set up a handler for capturing keyboard events using Vaadin Polymer GWT lib? How can I receive an event when keys like enter are pressed?**

Comment: what do you  want to do with the iron-list?
I can help you adding handlers for keys events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answering this question

> list.setKeyBindings(???);  // don't know how to use this function

according to `com/vaadin/polymer/vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements/1.2.3.1-SNAPSHOT/vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements-1.2.3.1-20160201.114641-2.jar!/com/vaadin/polymer/public/bower_components/iron-list/iron-list.html:292`

the `keyBindings` should have `object` of such structure:

```
    {
      'up': '_didMoveUp',
      'down': '_didMoveDown',
      'enter': '_didEnter'
    }
```

to construct such object, you can use following:

```
        new JSONObject() {{
            put("up", new JSONString("_didMoveUp"));
            put("down", new JSONString("_didMoveDown"));
            put("enter", new JSONString("_didEnter"));
        }}.getJavaScriptObject();
```

> I have no idea where I find the functions _didMoveUp, _didMoveDown and
>   _didEnter

they can be found here: `com/vaadin/polymer/vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements/1.2.3.1-SNAPSHOT/vaadin-gwt-polymer-elements-1.2.3.1-20160201.114641-2.jar!/com/vaadin/polymer/public/bower_components/iron-list/iron-list.html:1504`

here's the extract

```
    _didMoveUp: function() {
      this._focusPhysicalItem(Math.max(0, this._focusedIndex - 1));
    },

    _didMoveDown: function() {
      this._focusPhysicalItem(Math.min(this._virtualCount, this._focusedIndex + 1));
    },

    _didEnter: function(e) {
      // focus the currently focused physical item
      this._focusPhysicalItem(this._focusedIndex);
      // toggle selection
      this._selectionHandler(e.detail.keyboardEvent);
    }
```

> How can I set up a handler for capturing keyboard events using Vaadin
>   Polymer GWT lib?
>
> How can I receive an event when keys like enter are
>   pressed?

I could find this Polymer [convention](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html): properties not intended for external use should be prefixed with an underscore.

That's the reason why they are not exposed in `JsType` `IronListElement`.
You can change this function using `JSNI`. I think that smth like this:

```
    private native static void changeDidMoveUp(IronListElement ironList) /*-{
        var _old = ironList._didMoveUp;
        ironList._didMoveUp = function() {
            console.log('tracking');
            _old();
        }
    }-*/;
```

or add a new one

```
    IronListElement element ...

    com.vaadin.polymer.elemental.Function<Void, Event> func = event -> {
        logger.debug(event.detail);
        ...
        return null;
    };

    private native static void addUpdatePressed(IronListElement ironList, Function func) /*-{
        ironList._updatePressed = func;
    }-*/;

    {
        addUpdatePressed(element, func);
        element.addOwnKeyBinding("a", "_updatePressed");
        element.addOwnKeyBinding("shift+a alt+a", "_updatePressed");
        element.addOwnKeyBinding("shift+tab shift+space", "_updatePressed");
    }
```

should work. You can get element from `IronList#getPolymerElement()`.

keep in mind, that I haven't tested this code :)

Comment: Great answer, but can you please explain the last part after my last two questions a bit more detailed?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add key event custom element (I dont know if I understand correct the question)
You have to implement the  Polymer.IronA11yKeysBehavior behavior and then to use the `keyBindings` prototype property to express what combination of keys will trigger the event to fire.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
  
  <link rel="import" href="iron-a11y-keys-behavior/iron-a11y-keys-behavior.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-list/iron-list.html">
<body>
  
 <dom-module id="x-elem">

  <template>  
       <iron-list items="[[data]]" as="item">
    <template>
      <div>
        pressed: [[item]]
      </div>
    </template>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-elem',
    behaviors: [
      Polymer.IronA11yKeysBehavior
    ],
    properties: {
      preventDefault:{type:Boolean,value:true},
      data:{value:[]},
      keyEventTarget: {
        type: Object,
        value: function() {
          return document.body;
        }
      }
    },
    
    keyBindings: {
      '* pageup pagedown left right down up home end space enter @ ~ " $ ? ! \\ + : # backspace': '_handler',
      'a': '_handler',
      'shift+a alt+a': '_handler',
      'shift+tab shift+space': '_handler'
    },
    _handler: function(event) {
      if (this.preventDefault) {   // try to set true/false and press shit+a and press up or down
        event.preventDefault();
      }
      console.log(event.detail.combo);
      this.push('data',event.detail.combo);
      
    }
  });
  </script>
  <x-elem></x-elem>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope that answer your question how to listen to keys. the _handler function receive an event so you can look at the detail of the event and get the target (if something was in focus).

```
event.detail.target
```

Comment: Well this is the JavaScript solution. Please see my edit I need to know how it works with GWT Vaadin Polymer Elements.

Comment: I dont know GWT.. so I live the answer like this maybe someone will use it

Comment: When I do your code in JSNI I get: "A type with that name is already registered". This is because it is already defined. Is it possible to add the handler later on?

Comment: Still does not answer my question?